# generating bashrc variables & aliases from ansible : how to use prompt escape sequences

Tags: bash, ansible, escaping, prompt

I would use an ansible playbook to set up user's `.bashrc` & `.vimrc` to a standard.

I currently use few tasks & then :

```yaml
- name : few macros to vimrc
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ vimrc }}"
    line: '{{ item.line }}'
    state: present
  with_items:
    - { line : 'let @q = ":.!figlet\<CR>"' }
    - { line : 'let @b = ":.,.+5 s/./#&/\<CR>"' }
    - { line : 'let @A = "@qk@b\<cr>"'}


- name : few aliases & shortcuts for .bashrc
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ bashrc }}"
    line: '{{ item.line }}'
    state: present
  with_items:
    - { line : 'export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin' }
    - { line : 'alias df="df -h -text4"' }
    - { line : 'alias laptopsession="/home/francois/GITLAB/dev/dev_shell_privatework/laptopsession.sh"' }
    - { line : 'alias gitlognice="git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph"' }
    - { line : 'eval "$(thefuck --alias)"' }
```

this just works fine & as attended
if I add whatever a line is including any kind of \e[ escape sequence like this one for example

```yaml
- { line : 'export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\e[1;4;31m'' }
```

ansible crashes as :

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each: JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Syntax Error while loading YAML.   did not find expected ',' or '}'

The error appears to be in '/home/francois/GITLAB/dev/dev_vimrc_bashrc/vim2vimrc.yaml': line 112, column 46, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

        - { line : 'eval "$(thefuck --alias)"' }
        - { line : 'export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\e[1;4;31m''}
                                             ^ here This one looks easy to fix. It seems that there is a value started with a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended with the same kind of quote. For instance:

    when: "ok" in result.stdout

Could be written as:

   when: '"ok" in result.stdout'

Or equivalently:

   when: "'ok' in result.stdout"
```

while running the standard command :

```bash
ANSIBLE_NOCOWS=1  ansible-playbook  -i ./hosts vim2vimrc.yaml  -v
```

The issue I have it about line containing escaped sequences for bash coloration for example :

```bash
export PS1='\[\e[0;1;91m\]$?\[\e[0m\]-\[\e[0;1;92m\]\!\[\e[0m\]-\[\e[0;1;92m\]\#\[\e[0m\]-\[\e[0;1;91m\]\w \[\e[0;1;92m\]$ \[\e[0m\]'
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\e[1;32m'  
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\e[1;32m'
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\e[0m'  
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\e[0m'  
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\e[01;33m'  
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\e[0m'  
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\e[1;4;31m'
```

Those kind of escape sequence seems forbidden by ansible, so is there a way to insert those lines *(without the risk of making them double)* ?

Comment: Please edit your question with a [minimal complete and verifiable example](/help/mcve) showing how exactly you tried to insert those lines from the ansible playbook and the exact error (or unexpected result) your get.

Comment: juste the way I GAVE ALREADY  nothing more but the lines with export

Comment: You gave the lines as a bash script, not as how you implemented them in an ansible playbook. Since your problem is escaping, that makes a hell of a difference. Moreover, you did not give any information about the error/result you get.

Comment: no please read it it was already as yaml file was  for all of the working lines vs the one I would implement when someone GIVES the syntax ;) as giving any of the infinte solution that fails in nosens :)

Comment: => `- { line : 'export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$''\e[1;4;31m''' }`

Comment: [Learn yaml in y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/). Search for "espace".

Comment: I did read and before your latest edit, you had an example of a working implementation inside a yaml for some lines and a list of lines in a bash script you would like to implement in a yaml script but did not show as an example we could copy/paste as is. Your latest edit cleared the point and now we know it's a typo (escaping single quotes inside single quotes). We don't ask for MCVE by pure nastiness but because it helps everyone going down to the real problem.

Comment: ok I see, so having useless error I thought it was really worst & confusing. Therefore the solution you gave only works on single escape sequence inside the same line.

Comment: The doc I linked shows all possibilities of escapes for all types of strings in yaml (single quotes, double quotes, folded or litteral scalar blocks....).